# Groovy - groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder mkp.yield and mkp.yieldUnescaped

Tags: xml, groovy

One of the examples in the [Groovy documentation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/single-page-documentation.html) (with an additional println xml) is this:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

xml = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    records {
        car(name: mkp.yield('3 < 5'))
        car(name: mkp.yieldUnescaped('1 < 3'))
    }
}
println xml
assert xml.toString().contains('3 &lt; 5')
assert xml.toString().contains('1 < 3')
```

which outputs:

```
<records>3 &lt; 5
   <car name='3 &lt; 5'/>1 < 3
   <car name='groovy.xml.streamingmarkupsupport.StreamingMarkupWriter@152aa092'/>
</records>
```

Using `XmlUtil.serialize(xml)` results in a `SAXParseException` with a message saying that the content of the elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

I expected something more along the lines of

```
<records>
   <car name='3 &lt; 5'/>
   <car name='1 < 3'/>
</records>
```

Is this a bug or is the example just bad?

I'm using Groovy 2.4.8 with Java 8.

**EDIT:** Well, I just realized that of course it'll not be well-formed because the mkp.yieldUnescaped() for `1 < 3` creates an `<` which is reserved for tag names. Other than that, I'm still unsure why the mkp.yield's are putting the values in places other than the right side of the `name` attribute assignment.